# stop direct access url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

If user enters id in URL manually I would like them to be denied access like what codeigniter php has at the top of controller and models.

I have tried it but currently not working on edit. How can I get it to work.

But would like to still have access when click on edit button.

Keeps on saying  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\project\application\modules\admin\controllers\website\website.php on line 43`

```
public function edit() {
    if (!defined('base_url')) exit ('No direct script access allowed') {

     // If is ok.

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') { 
            $website_id = $this->uri->segment(4);

            $config_name = $this->input->post('config_name');
            $config_url = $this->input->post('config_url');
            $config_ssl = $this->input->post('config_ssl');
            $this->model_website->editWebsite($config_name, $config_url, $config_ssl, $website_id);

            $this->model_website_setting->editSetting('config', $this->input->post(), $website_id);
            redirect('admin/website');

        }

        $this->getForm();

    } else {

        return false;
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you got error

```
if (!defined('base_url')) exit ('No direct script access allowed') {
```

For this line `if` condition is terminated after `exit ('No direct script access allowed')`. then `else` is being without any `if`

I think what you are asking is like below

```
public function edit() {
    if(defined('base_url')){
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST'){
            $website_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
            $config_name = $this->input->post('config_name');
            $config_url = $this->input->post('config_url');
            $config_ssl = $this->input->post('config_ssl');
            $this->model_website->editWebsite($config_name, $config_url, $config_ssl, $website_id);           
            $this->model_website_setting->editSetting('config', $this->input->post(), $website_id);
            redirect('admin/website');
        }
        $this->getForm();

    }else{
        exit ('No direct script access allowed');
        return false;
    }
}
```